# How to include precision and scale parts in decimal column definition in liquibase?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, postgresql, liquibase

Let's say that I want to create some Number with 10 precision digit and 2 fraction digits like `0123456789.12`. Is there a way to define such a type and keep the column definition database agnostic? E.g. define a type that is converted by liquibase automatically to `DECIMAL(10, 2)` for Mysql and `NUMERIC(10, 2)` for postgres (or any other database).

Comment: According to the documentation for Liquibase's [column tag](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/column.html): "Also, specifying a java.sql.Types.* type will be converted to the correct type as well. If needed, precision can be included."  Therefore perhaps `java.sql.Types.DECIMAL(10, 2)`?

Comment: Actually, looking at the source of [`DecimalType.java`](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/master/liquibase-core/src/main/java/liquibase/datatype/core/DecimalType.java), I should think `DECIMAL(10, 2)` should work fine too?

Comment: For ```0123456789.12``` you need ```decimal(12,2)```. This may save someone's time.

Answer (score 7):

we use this column definition and it works:

```
<column name="lat" type="DECIMAL(12, 2)">
```